How to get the last "consume" of each product type for each unit produced?
I have an SQL table that's essentially just products being consumed in the fabrication process. I would like to (use what I think is the LAG function) return the last "consume" of each product type for each unit produced. There is also a timestamp attached to every Action (build or consume) if that helped.
I can start with a simple select statement to get something like this in Oracle:



Action
ProductName
ProductSerial




Build
Unit 9
1009


Consume
Product 1
E657


Build
Unit 8
1008


Build
Unit 7
1007


Build
Unit 6
1006


Build
Unit 5
1005


Consume
Product 3
D001


Build
Unit 4
1004


Build
Unit 3
1003


Build
Unit 2
1002


Build
Unit 1
1001


Consume
Product 3
C789


Consume
Product 2
B456


Consume
Product 1
A123



I have search forum after forum on other sites for a resolution. I want to be able to get this:



Action
ProductName
ProductSerial
Product1
Product2
Product3




Build
Unit 9
1009
Product 1 - E657
Product 2 - B456
Product 3 - D001


Consume
Product 1
E657





Build
Unit 8
1008
Product 1 - E123
Product 2 - B456
Product 3 - D001


Build
Unit 7
1007
Product 1 - E123
Product 2 - B456
Product 3 - D001


Build
Unit 6
1006
Product 1 - E123
Product 2 - B456
Product 3 - D001


Build
Unit 5
1005
Product 1 - E123
Product 2 - B456
Product 3 - D001


Consume
Product 3
D001





Build
Unit 4
1004
Product 1 - E123
Product 2 - B456
Product 3 - C789


Build
Unit 3
1003
Product 1 - E123
Product 2 - B456
Product 3 - C789


Build
Unit 2
1002
Product 1 - E123
Product 2 - B456
Product 3 - C789


Build
Unit 1
1001
Product 1 - E123
Product 2 - B456
Product 3 - C789


Consume
Product 3
C789





Consume
Product 2
B456





Consume
Product 1
A123






So every time there is a new "Build" action, I would like to return the last "Consume" for each of the products in the bill of materials. I’ve tried iterations of CASE statements but am unable to link the build to all of it’s components. Unfortunately, I can only reproduce the top table with a simple select statement:
Select
    Action as Build
    ,Product_Name as ProductName
    ,Product_Serial as ProductSerial
    ,Concat(Concat(Product_Name, ' - '), Product_Serial) as Barcode   (Not in Table 1 above)
Where Action in ('Build', Consume')
And Time_Stamp > sysdate - 90
From TraceDB
  

I know there has to be some sort of link to between Build timestamp and the Consume timestamp but I am drawing a blank and am 100% stumped.

I have left the tag dataiku, but I am not sure what it has to do with the question. Please reconsider if it's really relevant.

any sample data input for the expected output above? afaik LAG catches preceeding row for a given criteria (OVER).

There are too many questions left opened and result is not consistent with original data set, you must give more info about the rules and the number of "product" we may encounter per build line(and don't forget SQL doesn't support dynamic pivot in standard). Also you may need to take a look at FIRST_VALUE (and LAST_VALUE) analytic functions because in ORACLE they support quite a number of range parameters that may fit your needs. And if your requirements are too complicated for analytic functions you can still use the MODEL clause.

Try LAST_VALUE(...) around a DECODE or CASE that conditionally returns what you want when the action is "consume". Then add in the IGNORE NULLS option and the PARTITION BY, ORDER BY and ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW clauses.

In general, you'd be benefited by finding Oracle' SQL reference and reading through it to learn about all the functions available. Particularly the analytic functions: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Analytic-Functions.html#GUID-527832F7-63C0-4445-8C16-307FA5084056

Your sample data does not have a column on which the result set can be ordered; however, your query includes Where [...] Time_Stamp > sysdate - 90 so I am going to assume that you have a Time_Stamp column containing either a DATE or a TIMESTAMP data-type and that the rows in your table are in descending date-time order.
Given those assumptions, you can use the LAST_VALUE analytic function with CASE expressions:
SELECT action,
       productname,
       productserial,
       CASE action
       WHEN 'Build'
       THEN LAST_VALUE(
              CASE ProductName
              WHEN 'Product 1'
              THEN ProductName || ' - ' || ProductSerial
              END
            ) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY time_stamp)
       END AS product1,
       CASE action
       WHEN 'Build'
       THEN LAST_VALUE(
              CASE ProductName
              WHEN 'Product 2'
              THEN ProductName || ' - ' || ProductSerial
              END
            ) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY time_stamp)
       END AS product2,
       CASE action
       WHEN 'Build'
       THEN LAST_VALUE(
              CASE ProductName
              WHEN 'Product 3'
              THEN ProductName || ' - ' || ProductSerial
              END
            ) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY time_stamp)
       END AS product3
FROM   tracedb
WHERE  Action IN ('Build', 'Consume')
AND    Time_Stamp > sysdate - 90
ORDER BY time_stamp DESC;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE tracedb (Action, ProductName, ProductSerial, Time_Stamp) AS
  SELECT 'Build',   'Unit 9',    '1009', SYSDATE + 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Consume', 'Product 1', 'E657', SYSDATE + 19 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Build',   'Unit 8',    '1008', SYSDATE + 18 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Build',   'Unit 7',    '1007', SYSDATE + 17 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Build',   'Unit 6',    '1006', SYSDATE + 16 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Build',   'Unit 5',    '1005', SYSDATE + 15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Consume', 'Product 3', 'D001', SYSDATE + 14 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Build',   'Unit 4',    '1004', SYSDATE + 13 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Build',   'Unit 3',    '1003', SYSDATE + 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Build',   'Unit 2',    '1002', SYSDATE + 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Build',   'Unit 1',    '1001', SYSDATE + 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Consume', 'Product 3', 'C789', SYSDATE +  9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Consume', 'Product 2', 'B456', SYSDATE +  8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Consume', 'Product 1', 'A123', SYSDATE +  7 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



ACTION
PRODUCTNAME
PRODUCTSERIAL
PRODUCT1
PRODUCT2
PRODUCT3




Build
Unit 9
1009
Product 1 - E657
Product 2 - B456
Product 3 - D001


Consume
Product 1
E657
null
null
null


Build
Unit 8
1008
Product 1 - A123
Product 2 - B456
Product 3 - D001


Build
Unit 7
1007
Product 1 - A123
Product 2 - B456
Product 3 - D001


Build
Unit 6
1006
Product 1 - A123
Product 2 - B456
Product 3 - D001


Build
Unit 5
1005
Product 1 - A123
Product 2 - B456
Product 3 - D001


Consume
Product 3
D001
null
null
null


Build
Unit 4
1004
Product 1 - A123
Product 2 - B456
Product 3 - C789


Build
Unit 3
1003
Product 1 - A123
Product 2 - B456
Product 3 - C789


Build
Unit 2
1002
Product 1 - A123
Product 2 - B456
Product 3 - C789


Build
Unit 1
1001
Product 1 - A123
Product 2 - B456
Product 3 - C789


Consume
Product 3
C789
null
null
null


Consume
Product 2
B456
null
null
null


Consume
Product 1
A123
null
null
null



fiddle
